# HTML 5, display text based on value (without js)

Tags: html, css

So for a selection tag I can:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
</select>
```

My question is how do I do the opposite? As in, a value of "1" displays Volvo. I want to  display a text according to a value given, script free. Do I need to use CSS for it?

EDIT, my question was worded badly.

Suppose the server (rails) gives a value of "1", then I need the site to display "Volvo", if it gives "2", I need it to display "Saab". Note, I am not trying to create a selection box, I just want to display a text based on a number value given.

Comment: what do you mean opposite? Your question matches your code.

Comment: You want to change the text volvo or saab ? or append something to the text?

Comment: My question was worded badly, I altered it.

Comment: what do you mean, "the server gives a value" - that cannot happen with HTML and CSS alone?

Comment: Of course not, it's irrelevant how the value is retrieved. I want the html to display a certain text depending on the value being given without using scripting

Comment: You're probably looking for the `selected` attribute. How you choose which one is selected will depend on how you inject HTML.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at that, but that is still a form input attribute, does html not have some sort string to string look up table?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use javascript? It is far more suited to this than CSS.

Comment: How is a scripting language more suitable for something like this? I'd rather of done this in pure html if I could

Comment: HTML is a markup language, all it does is define a document. Browsers do all the rest. CSS is used by the browser to provide styling. Javascript is used by the browser to provide client-side interactivity. It is about using the right tool for the job. CSS is not the right tool here, javascript is for more suited to handling logic and data. Personally I'd take something akin to Johannes answer and just return name from the server.

Comment: "JS is for user interactivity, not for defining contents of a page" This is.... incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can as well use this:

```
<select>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

`value` is what will be sent via post or get after submitting the form, the text in between the `option` tags is what is displayed in the select menu.

REMARK AFTER CHANGED / EXTENDED QUESTION:

You are "not trying to create a select box", your "server gives a value":  This is very unclear. Are you talking about PHP? And why are you setting up a select menu if you don't want one?

If it's PHP,  just use an if/else clause like

```
if($value == 1) {
  echo "Volvo";
} else {
  echo "Saab";
}
```

Comment: If you have no value, then it'll just match innerHTML I think

Comment: I did not want to do the conversion server side, because I didn't think it was worth wasting server resources on something that should be done client side.

Comment: @Jay, but why disconnect the association between ID and Name? The server is where this exists. Use it. CSS is for styling, not content, and certainly not for data abstraction. Add a new make (or data item), you now have to update your CSS as well.

Comment: How is id and name disconnected? Name in this case is not a data value, just a display of a piece of data. I can store information as an int, and display it in what ever format I want

Comment: @Jay, you're relying on CSS to provide meaning to a value returned by rails, that seems pretty disconnected to me.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by using the CSS content tag

```
.x4:before {
   content: "Swamping";
}

.x5:before {
   content: "General Labour";
}
```

This lets me insert text depending on the selector

```
         <div class="x<%=  post.stuff.category %>"></div>
```

Now depending the value of the rails output, a different text is displayed. And this is done without javascript.

Comment: One day you will look back at this answer and realise while it solves the problem, and realise that it was a really bad idea to solve it this way.

Comment: Do you have a better way?

Comment: Wow, that's perversely roundabout. You're already generating the numeric classnames from the server; why not store the strings there too and draw those directly into the HTML?